# get thumbnail from video URL but it takes more than 5 seconds to load data on recycler view

Tags: android

1. I am using below code to get video list and thumbnail from video URL
   but it takes more than 5 seconds to load data on recycler view.

   ```
   public class VideoAsync extends AsyncTask {

       private static final String TAG = "VideoAsync";
       private VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
       private RecyclerView recyclerView;
       private List<Video> videoList;
       private Context context;

       public VideoAsync(RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context) {
           this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
           this.videoList = new ArrayList<>();
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

           return getAllMedia();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
           super.onPostExecute(o);
           videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getAllMedia(), context);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
           videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

       private List<Video>  getAllMedia() {
           HashSet<Video> videoItemHashSet = new HashSet<>();
           String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
   ```

   MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION};
               Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
   projection
                       , null, null, null);
               try {
                   cursor.moveToFirst();

   ```
               do{
                   Video video = new Video();

                   video.setVideoPath((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
                   video.setVideoTitle((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE))));
                   video.setVideoDuration(duration(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION))));
                   video.setThumbnail(getThumbNail((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))));
                   videoItemHashSet.add(video);

               }while(cursor.moveToNext());

               cursor.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           videoList.addAll(videoItemHashSet);
           Log.d(TAG, "getAllMedia: "+ videoList.size()) ;
           return videoList;
       }

       private static Bitmap getThumbNail(String imagePath){
           return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imagePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
       }

       private static String duration(String time){
           long duration = Long.parseLong(time);
           return  String.format("%d:%d",
                   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                           TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration))
           );
       }
   }


   //Video fragment
   ```

   Here, Adapter is set inside Videoasync class.
       public class VideosFragment extends Fragment {

   ```
       @BindView(R.id.rv_video) RecyclerView recyclerView;

       private VideoAsync videoAsync;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);
           ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
           setRecyclerView();

           return  view;
       }

       private void setRecyclerView(){
           recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
           videoAsync = new VideoAsync(recyclerView, getContext());
           videoAsync.execute();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Check the size of thumbnail.

Comment: private static Bitmap getThumbNail(String imagePath){
        return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imagePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    }// this method takes time to make thumbnail from url

Comment: If the size is big, it will take time to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is probably the one slowing down the loading process. The worst case is that it may throw an OOM Exception

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(imagePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

as of

```
video.setThumbnail(getThumbNail((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))));
```

it is always advised to only load the bitmap when needed unless there is a strict memory management in place. 
To save time i'd let the bitmap loading to Glide or any other similar library.
that said, change to:

```
do{
            Video video = new Video();

            video.setVideoPath((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
            video.setVideoTitle((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE))));
            video.setVideoDuration(duration(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION))));
            //video.setThumbnail(getThumbNail((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))));
            videoItemHashSet.add(video);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

and inside the **onBindViewHolder** of the recyclerView's adapter, load video the bitmap dynamically with Glide
ex:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(YourAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Video v = videoItemHashset.get(position);

        Glide.with(your_context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(v.getVideoPath())))
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.videoThumbnailImageView);

        holder.mPosition = position;///in case you're going to need it for playing the video at that position
    }
```